# Given $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, find the following and state any restrictions

Tags: functions

Given $f(x) = 3/(5-x)$ and $g(x) = 2x-1$ find the following and state any restrictions

```
 i) (f(g(x))

 ii) (g(f(sqrt2))
```

Here what I got for part i:

$g(x) = 2x-1$

$f(2x-1) = 3/(5-(2x-1))$
Restrictions: x≠3

$= 3/(-2x+6)$

So, $f(g(x)) = 3/(-2x+6)$

Is that correct?

Here is what I have tried for part ii:

[image]

**Where do I go from here?**

### EDIT 1:

[image]

How does this look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your process is correct.
Only a little mistake in part (ii): It should be $1+x$ not $1-x$

And for restriction, just looking at the denominators,I would like to state that for part (i) function $f(g(x))$ is not defined at $x=3$ and in case of part (ii) $g(f(x))$ is not defined at $x=5$.

Comment: I corrected part ii). I'm asked to rationalize the denominator in answer (for part ii). How do I do this? I believe it means I'm supposed to get ride of the radical...

Comment: Multiply denominator and numerator by $5+\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Noted. See edit for new solution..

Comment: Does (7+6sqrt2)/23 look right?

Comment: yes.correct.Just an advise in denominator while multiplying use $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$.It will save your time.